# how to change the background of the current line in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, vim, background

***Eclipse:***
[image]
just as you can see, now the current line in Eclipse is dark green, but i  want to change the current line to just a underline, just as what i make in vim, the underline is the current line:

***vim***
[image]

can eclipse make it? i have searched all i can, including preferences in eclipse and google, but still cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
:hi cursorline cterm=underline ctermbg=None
```

Comment: thx a lot, but i am new to eclipse, where to input the command?

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize you where using eclipse. This probably might not work using vrapper eclipse extension, if you're using that.

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find that option anywhere in the default options of the eclipse.

The only area I see to deal with the 'current line' theme is

```
Windows > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors
```

In this screen you should see the **Appearance colors options** which is where you can select the **Current line highlight**.

Another spot I checked is the **Annotations** section:

```
Windows > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations
```

But I did not see any kind of current line option.  You might have to try a 3rd party plugin for this.

Comment: thanks all the same, i have also checked the two places, and also find nothing.